# "FastCGI process exited unexpectedly" intermittently occurring on PDO connect with identical files

Tags: php, pdo, fastcgi, ms-access-2016

**NOTE:  This is a significant rewrite (and retitle) based on the last couple of days of poking at the problem since posting the original question.**

I have a PHP script that *used* to work but over the last several months it has begun failing intermittently.  When the script works it reads an XML file and then uses PDO to write data into a blank MS Access database file (a copy made earlier in the script of a pre-existing template file).

Historically it has been able to deal with 50+ MB XML files (it did back in December), but currently when the XML is *around* 300K in size the script intermittently fails with a "FastCGI process exited unexpectedly" error, the only error of significance I can find in the Failed Request Logging file generated by IIS, and unaccompanied by any error messages from PHP.

I say intermittently because with a file right on the borderline (e.g. 301K) I've had the script both successfully populate the .accdb file and fail.  Identical .accdb target, same source XML file, different behavior by FastCGI.  I should note that this all takes about 1 second from what I can see.

So, a) any idea what is going wrong, and b) any suggestions on how to squeeze more information out of PHP or the Failed Request Logging system?

UPDATE:  With a suggestion from @Darren I've discovered that after the "FastCGI process exited unexpectedly" error there's a subsequent "The extended attributes are inconsistent" message that I'm now looking into.

UPDATE 2:  So far I've shut off the UAC sound (a surprisingly effective fix for a lot of people getting the extended attributes error, but not me), and a `SFM /scannow` and `DISM` combo, but neither has helped.

Comment: No clue here, but just curious. I assume it still works when you access the database with Access 2016? An EOF is not all that strange, a database consist out of normal files, after all. Naively I could suspect that one of those files is corrupt. As I said: I've got no idea.

Comment: Random question, but do you close your php file with `?>` ?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware you were right, the EOF is a red herring, it shows up in both successful and unsuccessful runs (see my UPDATE above).

Comment: What's the status on that Access file? Did it grow over 2gb? Can you open it successfully or does it complain about corruption?

Comment: JNevill the Access file never gets touched when the script crashes, otherwise it inflates appropriately.

Comment: @Darren the PHP script executes successfully some of the time, so it isn't a tag issue.

Comment: @dspitzle You could potentially try what they did [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e66d981c-6987-47c3-b4d2-f632f1bfe2cd/fastcgi-process-exited-unexpectedly?forum=iissetup) to attempt to track down the issue via tracing?

Comment: @Darren I've got the Failed Request Tracing enabled, but the linked post got me looking at another error message I'd missed, "The extended attributes are inconsistent".  Unfortunately so far the suggestions I'm finding to fix that haven't eliminated the error message or the failures.

Comment: @dspitzle Interesting. I don't play around with windows servers much, but you might've come across [**this**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f41f04b-80d1-4d84-9663-4a77ac16616f/fastcgi-500?forum=iisfastcgimodule) ? I don't think it's to do with admin rights like [**this**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-10/quot-the-extended-attributes-are-inconsistent-quot-error-not/m-p/1545952) issue is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to make a long story short, I wound up installing the Access 2013 Redistributable, even though the ODBC drivers were clearly working because the .accdb file *could* populate under the correct circumstances.  I had needed to do it for a different machine which had the Click-to-Run version of Access installed, so I figured I might as well try it.  Installing the redistributable on the server where I was getting this flaky behavior allowed the script to run to completion without a hitch on any source file I threw at it.

So, if you are getting intermittent failures with PDO connecting to .accdb files via ODBC on a Windows machine, try the MS Access 2013 Redistributable, which is available from the Microsoft site at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358